# Icacls to change only files without full control permission

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, dropbox

I have a folder in my *inetpub* which holds thousands of images automatically copied from a *dropbox* account every 30 minutes.

In order for my *IIS* users to access those files, I need to give full control permissions to those files. I have a scheduled task running the following command every ten minutes to ensure proper permissions at all times.

The problem is that it seems to slow down my server when it runs. It's taking longer and longer to run too.

Is there a way to tell icacls to only change the files which don't have full control permissions?

```
icacls c:\inetpub\wwwroot\production\DigitalImages\*.* /grant builtin\iis_iusrs:f
```

Answer (score 0):

First idea: set up *icacls* action in synchronization clientside hook in dro[box client. But dropbox client [hasn't this kind of hooks](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/Client-side-sync-hook/td-p/143102).

In my opinion **the most correct way**: once to set up access rights to the root folder and enable rights inheritance.

```
icacls "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\production\DigitalImages" /grant "builtin\iis_iusrs:f" /inheritance:e
```

If the inheritance rights is disabled, you may need to reset it once to existing files.

```
icacls "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\production\DigitalImages\*.*" /q /c /t /reset
```